# Managing NuGet based libraries with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget

I'm currently investigating how to integrate using TFS with NuGet in our VS solutions. The reason for using NuGet is to get round the problem of shared libraries across different TFS branches. Normally we would have a solution which has a linked project (using relative pat) to the shared library, but our branching is at the project level so this linking would break.

The idea is to have shared libraries stored in TFS but then deployed to an internal NuGet server.

One problem I've come across is managing shared libraries stored within TFS whilst being able to pull out from NuGet debug and then commit.

An example

```
Solution A
 - Core Library
 - Project A1
 - Project A2
```

I want a developer to be able to open up the solution and have NuGet pull in the core library project (not just assemblies) so he can step into the source code and make necessary changes.  If he discovers a bug in the Core Library I want the developer to be able to :

1. make the change
2. re-test and debug
3. check-in the code.

I'm not sure how Step 3 would work. If the project is being brought in via NuGet then it won't be a TFS bound project would it?  How would the developer then make the change and be able to check it in?  Would he be forced to open up a separate project that IS bound to TFS, check that in then deploy to NuGet, then ensure Solution A does a re-get of the Core Library again.

I'm a little hazy as to how this can be achieved and what the recommended workflow is when working with NuGet, TFS and shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

With TFS you should be able to make at least the source stepping work as TFS supports source indexing out-of-the box. This doesn't require having to build `Project A` locally nor does the developer even need to have the sources for `Project A` -- VS will pull them automatically when debugging (assuming you've enabled source server support and configured your symbols correctly).

However, in order to make changes, the developer would need to properly checkout `Project A`. In order to test any changes to `Project A` locally, the developer would simply rebuild `Project A` use the build output as a local package source for NuGet.

This way, all it takes is running package restore locally for `Project B` (or whoever is the consumer of `Project A`).